# Why can't I drag and drop items from the assets folder to the game editor screen in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, drag-and-drop, assets

Recently I was working on a project in Unity3D, just a simple game. But when I tried to attach a material from the assets folder with the drag-and-drop function, it didn't work. Does somebody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Material is not a component. That why you cant attach it to a game object. You need to drag & drop it to Materials section in a Mesh Renderer.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If what you say is: cannot drag an asset from a folder into unity project, then maybe you are running Unity as admin (as "elevated process").

You can try to install Unity or Unity-hub in common files folder of your computer.